# Google Sheets - SUBTOTAL with Condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table that works well, but I have a problem when I want to apply filters and the table header.
I want that when I put a filter in column A or in column C, in cell D2, TO EXCLUDE THE CALCULATION of rows that are hidden by filtering (A kind of SUBTOTAL()).
Can someone help me with an idea?

`|
A              |               B              |                C               |         D          |                               E                                  |

| Number | Amount | Collected | SUM | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22SSS | 100 | TRUE | 101 | =sumif(C2:C;true;B2:B) |
| 55SSS | 50 | FALSE |  |  |
| 44SSS | 50 | FALSE |  |  |
| 33SSS | 1 | TRUE |  |  |
| 22SSS | 9 | FALSE |  |  |

When I apply filters in the table header, I would like it to calculate in D2, only in the visible rows

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding some aspect of your question, you are intending to filter using the filter menu option rather than a `filter` formula, so you should simply be able to use `=subtotal(109,B2:B)` to get the sum of all visible rows after filtering. However I would advise that you place the formula in D1 rather than D2, because if B2 is filtered out then D2 would also become hidden.

Comment: Correct, you are right, the Formula must be put in D1. 
But if I use 

> =subtotal(109,B2:B)

 I will not be able to condition the Amount, value of Column C (TRUE or FALSE)

Comment: Are you trying to apply a filter to hide rows on top of filtering by column C?